# discord.py - Adding a queue on a music bot for discord and search problems

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, queue, bots

in have 2 issues.

First, i tried to made a music bot for discord and it went good until i tried to play another song from it, to play another song (queue maybe?) i had to leave the bot from the voice channel and write the play command again (which is not what i wanted) and also tried to play from a music title and not only from url only (cause its a mess going to youtube and copy the link for every song i want to play) but it only works if i put the title between undescore (like "!play name_of_the_song") i tried a lot of things but none of them seems to work, so asking here is my last ham.

So what I want is to play the bot one song after another from the play command and that I can search for a song from its title without giving me another song that has nothing to do with what I am looking for

**What does my code look like right now:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from random import choice
import os, shutil


folder = 'music_files'

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''
ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'music_files/%(id)s.mp3',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

status = ['Jamming out to music!', 'Eating!', 'Sleeping!']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Bot is online!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='general')
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}!  Ready to jam out? See `?help` command for details!')

@client.command(name='ping', help='This command returns the latency')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'**Pong!** Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command(name='hello', help='This command returns a random welcome message')
async def hello(ctx):
    responses = ['***grumble*** Why did you wake me up?', 'Top of the morning to you lad!', 'Hello, how are you?', 'Hi', '**Wasssuup!**']
    await ctx.send(choice(responses))

@client.command(name='die', help='This command returns a random last words')
async def die(ctx):
    responses = ['why have you brought my short life to an end', 'i could have done so much more', 'i have a family, kill them instead']
    await ctx.send(choice(responses))

@client.command(name='credits', help='This command returns the credits')
async def credits(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Made by Danxx')
    await ctx.send('Thanks to `RK Coding` for the base code')

@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays music')
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop, stream=True)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))

@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")

@client.command(name='stop', help='This command stops the music and makes the bot leave the voice channel')
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await voice_client.stop()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    for song in os.listdir(folder):
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, song)
                try:
                    if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                        os.unlink(file_path)
                    elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                        shutil.rmtree(file_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Failed to delete %s. Reason %s' % (file_path, e))
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(choice(status)))


keep_alive()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Thanks for your help
NOTE: keep alive is a header i made for a keeping alive method  so the bot is online 24/7 so try to ignore it if you want to, also sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a queue for the guild to play music. Either using the builtin module queue, or just by using a list. Something like this would work:

```py
queue = {}
def addToQueue(guild, song):
    if guild.id in queue:
        queue[guild.id] = []
    queue[guild.id].append(song)

async def playSong(ctx, channel):
    async with ctx.typing():
        song = queue[channel.guild.id].pop(0, None)
        if song == None:
            return
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(song, loop=client.loop, stream=True)
        channel.play(
            player,
            after=lambda e:
            print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else await playSong(ctx, channel)
        )

    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))

@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays music')
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if channel != voice and voice is None:
        await channel.connect()
    elif channel != voice and voice is not None:
        await ctx.send("Already connected to a channel")
        return

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client
    addToQueue(ctx.message.guild, url)
    await playSong(ctx, voice_channel)
```

For your search issue, the code you provided doesn't seem to try to solve that. You will have to use Youtube API for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to implement the playSong method but shows me the "ctx is not defined" when i define it it brings the TypeError: playSong() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx', im missing something?

Comment: Oh, yeah I did some last minute changes to the code and forgot this. I've edited the answer, it should now be ok.